# Java LWJGL and JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, opengl, lwjgl, joptionpane

I have issues when using `javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Test:");` after `org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create();`. Here is a MCVE:

```java
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Frame;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

public final class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Display.setParent(canvas);
        Display.create();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Test:"); // Input dialog renders correctly but is completely freezed.
        // SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Test:")); // Input dialog is just white and doesn't respond.
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? How can I solve these issues? Note that it doesn't matter if use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Test:");` instead of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Test:");`. (This question is related to [Using javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog in Minecraft source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63757771/3882565).)

Comment: Is there anything I can do to solve the issue? Any workaround? E.g. temporarily disable the LWJGL stuff?

Comment: Sidebar: Java Swing & AWT GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT.